# Do Hamish, Hubert, and Harris Get Away with Murder?

Tags: brave

In the movie [Brave](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1217209/), Merida introduces her three brothers, Hamish, Hubert, and Harris, as such:

> The princes: Hamish, Hubert and Harris. Wee devils, more like. They get away with murder!

Normally, one would assume Merida is making the assertion idiomatically, however later in the film, we see the three boys participate in the throne-room brawl by dropping what appears to be a large morning star onto the head of a member of Clan Dingwall:

[image: Throne Room Brawl]

The weapon imparts enough force to cause the man's head to literally break through the stone floor, likely causing sufficient trauma for rapid, if not instant death. Meanwhile, the surrounding brawl, while likely to result in a few broken bones, appears largely non-fatal.

Normally, the boys' actions could be dismissed as unrealistic slapstick violence, however nowhere else in the film does any character suffer any trauma even remotely close to the level present in this scene.  The only thing that comes close is when one of the great circle stones crushes Mor'du, though this clearly does kill him.

After the brawl scene, the boys' actions are never again discussed. So, do the three brothers actually get away with murder?

Comment: Them Scots are being tough, ye ken? Ain't more than a wee knock.  Ach, he'll be fine after a strong dram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "they get away with murder" is shortly followed by "I can never get away with anything", and in this instance is definitely being used as the phrase (meaning to be able to do whatever one wants without punishment") rather than the literal definition.

At approx 20m 50s into the movie, as the clans are fighting, we see the boys smash the hammer into the unsuspecting clansman.

[image: Image 1 - Man about to taste a stone floor]
Image 1 - Man about to taste a stone floor

Now, after watching (in slow motion) the *whole* film where the clans were involved, I was unable to find this man again. So lets go via elimination. Immediately following this moment, the queen walks to Fergus, breaks up the fight by pulling the clan (chiefs?) into the front and center part of the room and announces the games to win Merida's hand. During this speech, we can see directly in front of the bench where the boys are sitting, but the man isn't there. As there wasn't really enough time for someone to move him (as they were all involved in either the fight or staring at the queen as she walked by), it's assumed that he got up by himself.

[image: Image 2: No man in front of the chair]
Image 2: No man in front of the chair

I'm sorry I can't offer any better proof - there doesn't appear to be any - at least none that is visible on dvd.

Comment: They seem to know many hideouts and passages in the castle. That man will never be found :-P